# MediaElements.js - Flash fallback does not stream MP4 from subdirs

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using FMS to stream MP4 over RTMP. The client is using MediaElements.js. In Firefox this is successfully falling back to the Flash player, as it should. When I place an MP4 in the top level folder of the video application instance, the playback succeeds. When I create subdirectories and place video there, playback fails. For example, a src like  . . .

```
rtmp://servername/video/\_definst\_/mp4:DELTA2.mp4
```

. . . plays back fine. While a src URL like . . .

```
rtmp://servername/video/\_definst\_/mp4:/data/DELTA2.mp4
```

. . . fails.

I think the problem is in the way the player is interpreting\sending the application instance in its request to FMS. So in the first example above, I can see in the FMS access log an `x-appinst` of . . .

```
\_definst\_
```

. . . while in the second case I see an x-appinst of . . .

```
\_definst\_/mp4:/data
```

The second case is clearly wrong. The fact that the second URL works in a separate custom Flash player makes me believe that it must be the client that is incorrectly sending the request somehow.

Any thoughts? Anyone been able to stream video from FMS to the MediaElements flash player from some directory other than root?